# How do I read the individual bytes of a file

Tags: .net, compression, arrays

I am trying to determine whether or not a file has been compressed with the GZip protocol.

The consensus seems to be that I need to read the first two bytes of the file, and check that they are equal to `0x1f8b`. I have just learned that this is known as a magic number.

How do I, preferably using .Net/C# as this is what I am used to, read the individual bytes of a file?

Thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try this...

you might need to use a different variable type for v or you could convert the int...

```
using (BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader(File.Open("file.bin", FileMode.Open)))
{
    int v = b.ReadByte();
    Console.WriteLine(v);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to read the two (first) bytes of a file is to open a FileStream and then read just the two bytes:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream( "D:\\path_to_file\file.ext", FileMode.Open);
int value = fs.ReadByte();
...
```

Of course you should check if file exist, catch the exception if app is not running with enough permission to read the file, close the stream (access to file) when you're done with it...

It may be more convenient to use FileStream's `Read` method (which allows you to read many bytes at once). Please note, that there is also asynchronous equivalent of this method available.

Answer (score 0):

Usually in common x86, char is a byte-long data type, so reading first two chars of the file will do.